# Extract a service's clusterIP using go in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes

Suppose there is a service with name "SVC", running in namespace NS in kubernetes cluster. I need to extract its IP (i.e clusterIP)

I could write some code (below), which works, but I think this approach should not be taken. As this code will be called frequently, loading config every time is a waste. How should I  better do it:

```
namespace := "NS"
serviceName := "SVC"
clusterIP := ""

kubeconfig := filepath.Join(
     os.Getenv("HOME"), ".kube", "config",
)

config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("BuildConfigFromFlags Failed")
    return string(""), err
}

clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("NewForConfig Failed")
    return string(""), err
}

svcList, err :=  clientset.CoreV1().Services(namespace).List(metav1.ListOptions{
    FieldSelector: "metadata.name=" + serviceName,
    })

//fmt.Printf("kubecofig: %s\n",kubeconfig)
//fmt.Printf("config: %#v", config)
//fmt.Printf("nameSpaceList: %#v", svcList)
for _, svc := range svcList.Items {
    clusterIP = svc.Spec.ClusterIP
    break
}

fmt.Printf("Service IP: %s", clusterIP)
```

Is there a way I can write concise code like this and get my desired result. If there is a way to use  "&corev1.service"  , can anybody please tell me how?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, you code seems to be working just fine. If you want to get a specific service, you could use the `metav1.ListOptions` to add some selection criteria.

Comment: Can't this be done without BuildConfigFromFlags() and NewForConfig(). AFAIK, these will involve the configuration to be loaded parsed (not sure if i m correct). If there is more efficient way, please let me know. My quest was that.

Comment: No, this is how the API works. You load your cluster configuration from your kube config, you initialize a client using the config and then you call API methods to get the information you need. It is similar in other languages as well, it is not just Go

Comment: This is exactly what kubectl does every time you run it. It reads your configuration, authenticates with the cluster and then executes the APIs

Comment: If you are going to call the APIs many times in the same program, yes, you should initialize the client once and then pass a reference to it whenever you need to call something.

Comment: Can you just directly use the [DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) `SVC.NS.svc.cluster.local`?